# In App Email - MFMailComposeViewController - Error Message

Tags: objective-c, email, ios7, viewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My code is as follows:

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyScene.h"
#import "MainMenu.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)showMailPicker:(id)sender
{
 // You must check that the current device can send email messages before you
 // attempt to create an instance of MFMailComposeViewController.  If the
 // device can not send email messages,
 // [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] will return nil.  Your app
 // will crash when it calls -presentViewController:animated:completion: with
 // a nil view controller.
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
      // The device can send email.
 {
      [self displayMailComposerSheet];
 }
 else
      // The device can not send email.
 {
      self.feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
      self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send mail.";
 }
}


- (IBAction)showSMSPicker:(id)sender
{
 // You must check that the current device can send SMS messages before you
 // attempt to create an instance of MFMessageComposeViewController.  If the
 // device can not send SMS messages,
 // [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] will return nil.  Your app
 // will crash when it calls -presentViewController:animated:completion: with
 // a nil view controller.
 if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
      // The device can send email.
 {
      [self displaySMSComposerSheet];
 }
 else
      // The device can not send SMS.
 {
      self.feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
      self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Device not configured to send SMS.";
 }
}


- (void)displayMailComposerSheet
{
 MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

 [picker setSubject:@"Support for Brick Smasher Extreme"];

 // Set up recipients
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"help.bricksx@gmail.com"];
 //NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"second@example.com",     @"third@example.com", nil];
 //NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"fourth@example.com"];

 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 //[picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
 //[picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

 // Attach an image to the email
 //NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rainy" ofType:@"jpg"];
 //NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
 //[picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"rainy"];

 // Fill out the email body text
 NSString *emailBody = @"Message:";
 [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

 //[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
 [[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:picker
                                                                                          animated:YES
                                                                              completion:nil];
}



- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
 self.feedbackMsg.hidden = NO;
 // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
 switch (result)
 {
      case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
           self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending canceled";
           break;
      case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
           self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail saved";
           break;
      case MFMailComposeResultSent:
           self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sent";
           break;
      case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
           self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail sending failed";
           break;
      default:
           self.feedbackMsg.text = @"Result: Mail not sent";
           break;
 }

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

The error is: `Warning: Attempt to present <MFMailComposeViewController: 0xbf95170> on <UIViewController: 0xbf78d10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

I'm trying to send email through my app. Using `MFMailComposeViewController`, it always gives an error (above). But when I use the SMS part, there is no problem at all.

Using: Xcode 5, iOS 7, iPhone Retina 4"

Comment: Please do some searching on the error: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=attempt+to+present+whose+view+is+not+in+the+window+hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely here:
`[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:`

First of all, you're already calling this from a ViewController, so you can just `[self presentViewController:]`. It does sound like maybe you're calling your `displayMailComposerSheet` before `ViewController`'s view is visible (`viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` maybe), which would raise the error you're seeing.

Comment: When I use the [self presentViewController:picker animated: YES.....] the app crashes with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException and my viewDidLoad/viewWillAppear is above these statements

Answer (score 0):

use

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentViewController:picker                                                                             animated:YES                                                                              completion:nil];
```